# htaccess redirect issue mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

hey well I'm trying to change the url structure using the htaccess file and I'm rewriting my old structure to the new one, although I'm having some issues.

I'm using the following code

```
RewriteRule video-(.*)-(.*).html?$ http://mysite.com/download-$2-video-$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Now the problem I'm running into is that when I try to redirect something like

```
http://mysite.com/video-1-this-is-the-title.html
```

it's redirecting it to

```
http://mysite.com/download-this-video-1.html
```

instead of

```
http://mysite.com/download-this-is-the-title-video-1.html
```

if anyone could help that would be great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first backreference is always going to be numbers, you could try changing your regular expression to:

```
RewriteRule video-([0-9]+)-(.+).html?$ http://mysite.com/download-$2-video-$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks but I tried that and I'm still encountering the same issue :(